polars: Enabling global string cache creates smaller parquet files
Summary of the problem
Changes made to code
I have a daily job (written in python using polars) that pulls some data from an API, transforms it, and saves it to a parquet file. A number of the columns are stored as categorical because they have a very small number of possible values. For unrelated reasons, I recently enabled the polars global string cache so I could join with another dataframe.
Effect on file size
After merging my changes, I saw that the new parquet files were about half the size they usually are. At first I thought there was simply less data being saved, but after investigation, it had the correct number of rows, and all the data seemed as expected.
Question
Is it possible that enabling the global string cache caused this change in file size? If so, why?

Did you try to writing a minimal example dataframe (with random data) to a parquet file with/without the global string cache enabled?

I tried as you suggested, and found no difference in file size
